# Значение поля input из ссылки

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Есть много полей инпутов, каждая из них относиться к определенной категории. И есть много ссылок которые тоже распределены по категориям. Но вопрос в том что Как сделать так чтоб когда пользователь делает двойной клик по ссылке то его значение автоматически попадает в значение поля input. Может кто то где то видел подобный скрипт. Подскажите пожалуйста.

PS подобное я видел в стоматологической программе ident по моему называется. Но она десктопная а мне нужно браузерное решение. Спасибо

**Найденный пример:**

```js
function getText(el) {
  document.getElementById('field').value = el.firstChild.data;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field" value="">
<br />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getText(this)" id="text">Text</a>
<br />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getText(this)" id="text2">Text 2</a>
<br />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getText(this)" id="text3">Text 3</a>
```

Comment: Приложите может пример кода, чтобы на его основе можно было решение построить

Comment: сделайте лучше галочку "default", неочевидны все эти даблклики в веб

Comment: Никакого кода нет.Думал может есть готоый плагин какой нить

Comment: Нашёл вроде <script type="text/javascript">
function getText(el){
 document.getElementById('field').value = el.firstChild.data;
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="field" value=""><br />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getText(this)" id="text">Text</a><br />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getText(this)" id="text2">Text 2</a><br />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getText(this)" id="text3">Text 3</a><br />
</script>

Comment: Теперь собственно и вопрос стал понятнее. Но как сделать чтоб при нажатии второй ссылки значение первой ссылки не "стиралось" а наборот значение второй ссылки добавлялось через запятую

Answer (score 0):

> Но как сделать чтоб при нажатии второй ссылки значение первой ссылки не "стиралось" а наборот значение второй ссылки добавлялось через запятую

Как-то так:

```js
var values = [];

function setValue(el) {
  let textValue = el.firstChild.data;

  var index = values.indexOf(textValue);
  if (index !== -1) {
      values.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
      values.push(textValue)
  }
  
  document.getElementById('field').value = values.join(', ');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field" value="">
<br />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setValue(this)" id="text">Text</a>
<br />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setValue(this)" id="text2">Text 2</a>
<br />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setValue(this)" id="text3">Text 3</a>
```

Comment: помог вот этот код <script type="text/javascript">
function getText(el){
    document.getElementById('jaloby').value += ', ' + el.firstChild.data;
}
</script>

Comment: @AlexStassov а если дважды кликнуть? Будет два этих элемента